# CakePHP Mysql query with AND condition

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am running a Mysql query in CakePHP but it is not outputting any result though no error is displayed.

Mysql query is this:

```
SELECT `isbn`, `title`, `author_name` FROM `books` WHERE `author_name` = 'William Rice' AND `title` LIKE '%Course%' ORDER BY `title` ASC
```

and it outputs results.

And I have written this in CakePHP find function:

```
$books = $this->Book->find('all', array('fields'=>array('Book.isbn', 'Book.title', 'Book.author_name'),
                                                'conditions'=>array('Book.author_name'=>'William Rice', 
                                                                    'AND'=>array('Book.title'=>'LIKE %Course%')),
                                                'order'=>'Book.title ASC',
                                                  ));
```

But the query doesn't run. Is AND condition specified like this? Please have a look at it and tell me where is it wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    $books = $this->Book->find('all', array(
        'fields' => array('Book.isbn', 'Book.title', 'Book.author_name'),
        'conditions' => array(
            'Book.author_name'=>'William Rice',
            'Book.title LIKE'=>'%Course%'
        ),
        'order'=>'Book.title ASC',
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use AND array:

You have to change your query as given below:

```
$books = $this->Book->find('all', 
array('fields'=>array('Book.isbn', 'Book.title', 'Book.author_name'),
      'conditions'=>array('Book.author_name'=>'William Rice',
                          'Book.title LIKE'=>'%Course%'),
      'order'=>'Book.title ASC'
      ));
```

Comment: Anubhav thanks but I already tried what you suggested. LIKE will be appended to Book.tite

Answer (score 0):

You have done only one mistake , Remove 'AND' from your query, after removing 'AND' your query will be like below query.

```
$books = $this->Book->find('all', array(
        'fields' => array('Book.isbn', 'Book.title', 'Book.author_name'),
        'conditions' => array(
            'Book.author_name'=>'William Rice',
            'Book.title LIKE'=>'%Course%'
            ),
        'order'=>'Book.title ASC',
        )
    );
```

Comment: Thank you urdesh, but even with that AND the query runs fine. The only problem is LIKE should be with fieldname not with value. Such use of AND is valid but redundant in this case because it defaults to AND. For OR condition it is done that way.